# Using an object to instantiate a collection

Tags: java, generics, collections

I would like to do the following (which doesn't work, it is just to explain the concept). Any idea how to do it?

```
Class type;
if (/* something */)
  type = String.class;
else
  type = Boolean.class;

return new ArrayList<type>();
```

`ArrayList<type>` doesn't work. I tried with `type.getClass()`, doesn't work either.

Comment: What is the return type of your method? There would be no observable difference if you *could* do that. Could you provide a slightly more extensive sample of what you want to do?

Comment: It's not a return in my code, it's more like `this.someField = new ArrayList<type>();`. The complete method is a bit too complicated, I just ask about how to do that collection instantiation.

Comment: @Ottarus: then I ask: how is `someField` declared? How would you notice a difference? If you can't tell us how you'll use it, then we can't tell you how it should be done.

Comment: It's `private ArrayList<Object> someField;`.

Comment: I think you could use generic wildcard. So your field declaration will be `private List<?> field;`. And then in the code you can assign more specific instance using the method I provided in my answer.

Comment: Oltarus: in that case you can just assign a `ArrayList<Object>`: there's no difference at runtime. You *might* be interested in [`Collections.checkedList()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#checkedList(java.util.List,%20java.lang.Class)) however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap it into the method, pass the type as generic `Class` and let Java do the rest for you. No need for any conditional branching.

```
<T> List<T> newList(Class<T> type) {
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
List<String> list = newList(String.class);
```

Bear in mind that `T` does not have to be specified at the *generic class* level. You can specify generic type for the method and therefore make it a *generic method* as in the example code.

Comment: Very interresting! I need to have a conditional branching, but I keep that in mind for later use.

Comment: Why do you think you need your `if` int there?

Comment: It depends of some parameter. `if (arg1.equals("yes"))`. If I had an `if` that only checked if something was a `String`, an `Integer` or a `Boolean`, I wouldn't have to have a test, I agree...

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that. Your check happens at runtime and generics are lost after compilation.

The only purpose of generics is to guarantee type-safety at compile-time. In your example you want to determine the type at runtime.

What you can do is to instantiate a differently-typed collection in each `if`.

Comment: Thanks for your precise and complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

you should use:

```
public ArrayList<?> getList() {
    if (/* something */) {
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    } else {
        return new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Type information is deleted by the Java compiler but can be accessed through additional packages such as [this one](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/)

Answer (score 0):

`type` isn't a `class` , You can have multiple return in this case
You can have this

```
public <T> List<T> foo(T type) {
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

Comment: You don't even need the parameter. And if you lose it (and make it `static`), then you'll have re-implemented the Guava method [`Lists.newArrayList()`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList()).

Answer (score 0):

The if clause is presumably something that is decided at run-time. The parameterised types in java are cleared at compile time. Just returning new ArrayList() will have the same effect.